# homography and image scaling in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, coordinate-transformation, homography

I am calculating an homography between two images `img1` and `img2` (the images contain mostly one planar object, so the homography works well between them) using standard methods in OpenCV in python. Namely, I compute point matches between the images using sift and then call `cv2.findHomography`.

To make the computation faster I scale down the two images into `small1` and `small2` and perform the calculations on these smaller copies, so I calculate the homography matrix `H`, which maps `small1` into `small2`.
However, at the end, I would like to use calculate the homography matrix to project one full-size image `img1` onto the other the full-size image `img2`.

I thought I could simply transform the homography matrix `H` in the following way `H_full_size = A * H * A_inverse` where `A` is the matrix representing the scaling from `img1` to `small1` and `A_inverse` is its inverse. 
However, that does not work. If I apply `cv2.warpPerspective` to the scaled down image `small1` with `H`, everything goes as expected and the result (largely) overlaps with `small2`. If I apply `cv2.warpPerspective` to the full size image `img1` with `H_full_size` the result does not map to `img2`.

However, if I project the point matches (detected on the scaled down images) using `A` (using something like `projected_pts = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, A)`) and then I calculate `H_full_size` from these, everything works fine.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, the problem is that homography applies a perspective projection which is a non linear transformation (it is linear only while homogeneous coordinates are being used) that cannot be represented as a normal transformation matrix. Multiplying such perspective projection matrix with some other transformations therefore produces undesirable results.

You can try multiplying your original matrix H element wise with:

S = [1,1,scale ; 1,1,scale ; 1/scale, 1/scale, 1]

H_full_size = S * H

where scale is for example 2, if you decreased the size of original image by 2.

Comment: I came to the same, well "scale-inversed", solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48915151/2057762

Answer (score 0):

I think your wrong assumption in this passage

> `H_full_size = A * H * A_inverse` where `A` is the matrix representing the scaling from img1 to small1

derives from humans "love" from symmetry. Out of the joke, your formula is correct after introducing an hypotesis that I am going to expose.
If I start from this consideration (this is quite equivalent of the cv2 function cv2,warpPerspective - the formula is true with respect to a scale factor)

```
img2 = H_fullsize*img1
```

you can derive your own formula.

```
small2 = B*img2
small1 = A*img1
small2 = H*small1
B*img2 = H*A*img1
```

that is quite equivalent (if B is invertible)

```
img2 = B_inverse*H*A*img1
```

and the question became

```
H_fullsize = B_inverse*H*A
```

So the question became: are you sure that the scale matrix from `img1` to `small1` is equal to the scale matrix from `img2` to `small2`? (or at least they differs of a constant scale factor value) ?

If it is your case, remember that, as you write, homograpy works **only** between planar images (or in a case of pure rotation). Assuming you have 80% SIFT points on a plane and 20% points out of this plane, the homograpy considers all this points as they were in a plane and find the transformation H that minimize errors (*and not the perfect one only for the 80% points in a plane*). 
Also errors that are evident in a 1080p resolution image could be not so evident in a 320p resolution image (you do not specify **how much** you reduce the images!)

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes, img1 and img2 and the same size and they are scaled down by the same factor -- sorry I should have made this clearer in the original post. So in your terms A is the same as B