# Does the homography matrix account for scale?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography

From what I understand, the homography matrix only accounts for rotation and translation, but maybe I am wrong about this.

Comment: The full 9x9 homography matrix (2D) with 8 degrees of freedom can handle scale, rotation, shearing, translation and projectivity. In short: it can handle any plane-to-plane transformation. Other forms have different degrees of freedom. For example in 3D rendering you are often interested only in a 3D rigid transformation, where scaling isnt wanted, because you dont want to distort 3D models, you only want to give them another pose.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to programming, but to the math/geometry behind computer vision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the first two elements on diagonal of the homography matrix are for the scale in x and y axis respectively.
Have a look at the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019338/how-to-change-the-homography-with-the-scale-of-the-image/48915151).